# postfix to a parseInt resulting in error

Tags: c, postfix-operator

The line: n2[i-dec-1] = parseInt(n2[i-dec-1])++;

The error: "invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation."

solution: n2[i-dec-1] = parseInt(n2[i-dec-1])+1;

I am curious why the postfix has issue with the parseInt value from the array, (which resolves to 0).

ANSWER: turns out that postfix to an integer is not sound.  That that process results in an error.

Comment: Exactly: because the ++ doesn't stand for "+1", it stands for "+=1", as in "x=x+1", where x is a variable, not a constant (like the result of a function). Please answer your own question, and mark it as accepted answer when you can.

Answer (score 3):

ANSWER: turns out that postfix to an integer is not sound. That that process results in an error.

The postfix can only be used on a variable not a function return value which is an integer ( such as parseInt()'s return value).

var n=1; n++; good.
1++; no good.